# Set background color according to text recycler view Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've a simple recycler-view which has a list of names.
Now what I want to achieve is like if the name starts with A the color should be red and if it starts with B it should be blue and so on. How can I do it?

Comment: *background color of the view holder

Comment: what have you tried? seems pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter you can change your ViewHolder background to which color you want.